# docker-compose NPM container keeps restarting

Tags: node.js, npm, docker-compose

I am trying to create a container that is just running cli scripts. At the moment I do not have the scripts written I'm just trying to get the container started first. The following set up creates the container fine, but it keeps restarting and after spending hours trying to find a solution on line I've not got any closer to a solution:

DockerFile

```
FROM node:18-alpine
WORKDIR /src
COPY package*.json /
EXPOSE 3000

RUN npm install -g nodemon && npm install
COPY . /
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  calculations-script:
    restart: unless-stopped
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: DockerFile
    command: npm run dev
    volumes:
      - ./:/src
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "test-nodejs-script",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Test script",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "node index.js"
  },
  "author": "Testing",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Comment: Your container keeps restarting because of this line in `docker-compose.yaml` file -     `restart: unless-stopped`. I didn't really get what's the problem, because it should has behaviour like this in that case.

Comment: Thanks dokichan, but I need the container to stay active and not just start up then stop.

Answer (score 0):

You container is restarting because of the `restart` field in your manifest which is set at `unless-stopped`. `unless-stopped` ensure that container is always restarted unless manually stopped.

What you probably want is `no` or `on-failure`, [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#restart) for more details

Comment: Thank you for your response. The issue with this change is that the container starts runs the script and stops. I need the container to remain active.